# Computation of fundamental units

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Given a number field $K$, is there an algorithm that returns a basis for the group $O_K^\times$?

When I google around, there seems to be lots of algorithms to do this in specific cases, but I cannot find a reference that says it is doable in general.

So is there such an algorithm, and is there a good reference that outlines one?

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_K = B \mathbb{Z}^k$ for some integral basis $B$. After removing the torsion $\log \mathcal{O}_K^\times$ is a "lattice of [rank $r$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_unit_theorem)" in $\mathbb{C}$.
So I would search for elements $\alpha = B n, n \in \mathbb{Z}^k, |n_i| \le C,N(\alpha) = 1$ and stop when $\log \alpha$ generates a group of rank $r$.

Comment: You might search for how to compute *regulators*; I imagine algorithms for that are likely to produce a basis. Material on computing *class groups* might be a source of references as well, since I believe some of the general algorithms need the regulator, and generate the data needed to find generators for the unit group anyways.

Comment: @reuns: There are two problems with that: **(1)** you might compute a basis for a proper subgroup of the unit group, and **(2)** units may be so big you can't reasonably write down the $n_i$ vectors.

Comment: @Hurkyl With $\sigma$ the embedding $K \to \mathbb{C}^r$, I could compute $\log \sigma(bn)$ for many $n$, test many linear combinations trying to fall in the sum-zero (unit) subspace, and use the regulator (obtained from the residue of $\zeta_K$ and the class number) to check if I found the whole unit lattice ?

Comment: @reuns: I have the vague impression that the general algorithms compute both the class group and unit group simultaneously (using $\zeta_K$ as check): that there isn't really a good way to compute the class number separately